# Duplicating movie clips in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Say I have a movieclip called mcLoader and within it I have some loaded bitmap image (don't know the name, it's dynamically loaded).

How do I copy that bitmap image into a movieclip mcContainer?

Comment: When you load the images, you could add them to an array to keep track of them.

Comment: but I need the same image at two places at once

Comment: once you can reference it, checkout the clone() or draw() methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will copy every content of mcLoader and put it in mcContainer:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

for (var i:int = 0; i < mcLoader.numChildren; i++)
{
    var obj = mcLoader.getChildAt(i);
    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(obj.width, obj.height);
    var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    bmd.draw(obj);

    mcContainer.addChild(bm);
}
```